# Can I process the JSON result with a new script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have my getJSON result being processed in the same script. Now I want to add previous and next buttons to get those records. The getJSON request will be different but the processing of the result will be the same. So I guess my question is can I send the result of getJSON to another script for processing and how?

Here is my get and first line of processing.

```
$.getJSON("loadloads.php", function(data){

$("#LoadNumber").val(data[0].value.LoadNumber); 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a generic named function and pass the reference to to the method:

```
var jsonhandler = function(data){
    $("#LoadNumber").val(data[0].value.LoadNumber); 
};

$.getJSON("loadloads.php", jsonhandler);
```

Comment: that did it thanks. I tried using a different var name earlier but it didn't work. I had to go through and re )} things so they were in the proper order but it working now thanks again.